# Why does this code give me a -19 as the result?

Tags: r

Why does this code give me a -19 as the result? Let's think about how this code works. If we input x = 19 and y = -95, we get r = -19 I guess, which is false so the ifelse statement should simply return the y value, which is -95. Why does it return -19 instead?

```
gcd <- function(x,y) {
  r <- x%%y
  return(ifelse(r, gcd(y, r), y))
}
gcd(19,-95)
```

Comment: Only 0 is FALSE.  Everything else is TRUE.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, why do you say that only 0 is FALSE? 

For example, when I try this code I get FALSE as well.

a<-as.logical(4%%2)

Comment: Try `ifelse(seq(-3, 3), 1, 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you want get gcd of negative numbers you need to get absolute value of them.

gcd(,)=gcd(||,||)

```
gcd <- function(x,y) {
  r <- abs(x%%y)
  return(ifelse(r, gcd(y, r), y))
}
gcd(19,-95)
```

Here you can learn more

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/GCD_for_Negative_Integers